# Can mysqli connection work in parallel?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm developing a PHP application which requires to perform several database transactions.

I've created a singleton which I retrieve like this:

```
$db = DBHelper::getInstance();
```

And it does the following

`self::$conn = new mysqli( self::DBServer, self::DBUser, self::DBPass, self::DBName );`

Then, I've several utility methods.

Read the following code:

```
$sql = "SELECT `id`, `name`  FROM lamp";
    $statement = self::$conn->prepare( $sql );
    $statement->execute();
    $statement->bind_result( $id, $name );

    $lamps = array();
    while( $statement->fetch() )
    {
        $lamp = self::getLampById($id);
        array_push($lamps, $lamp);
    }
```

And method getLampById is exactly:

```
$sql = "SELECT `id`, `name` FROM lamp WHERE `id` = ?";

    $statement = self::$conn->prepare( $sql );
    $statement->bind_param( 'i', $id );
  [...]
```

This last line, which binds param, crashes with a:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in...

I guess it's because I'm using the same `$conn` variable. Note that if I save those ID's, I close the `$conn` and then request every lamp by its ID, it's working, because I'm opening and closing the connection constantly.

I understand this, as I'm using a singleton.

But now imagine I run this PHP script twice at the same exact second. Will Two "threads" work with the same code and properties?

I'm a little bit lost how does PHP execute it's code.

Hope I've explained myself good enough.

Thanks.

Comment: you can have multiple connections open, but since PHP is single-threaded and the individual query() calls will block, you can't issue two queries in parallel and sit back to wait for either to respond. PHP itself will enforce serial execution of the queries.

Comment: So two executions on the same php file, will never collide, right?

Comment: php does not have threads, a singleton in php is only unique to the particular page cycle, 100 different users will access 100 different instances of this singleton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting a comment, as he's not writing an answer:

> php does not have threads, a singleton in php is only unique to the particular page cycle, 100 different users will access 100 different instances of this singleton –  [Steve](https://stackoverflow.com/users/574632/steve)

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can do this as far as I am aware would be by using pthreads, pcntl_fork or [reactphp](http://reactphp.org/).

Answer (score -4):

You code fails because of a typo in the line:

```
$sql = "SELECT `id`, `name`FROM lamp WHERE `id` = ?";
                           ^-- missing space
```

And for no other reason.

Check your function returns:

```
if( ! $statement = self::$conn->prepare( $sql ) ) {
  throw new Exception($conn->error);
}
```

As for your "parallelism" question, your singleton class is instantiated per-script, not as a single object for every user that makes a request. The are no concurrency concerns.